# Excel - VBA play mp3 stream

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to play a stream from Excel like this one:

```
https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Bonjour&tl=fr&client=tw-ob
```

My goal is that in Excel I can have a French word and listen to it by clicking on a cell:

So far I just tried to put the URL in the function like that:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else

Sub TranslateAndSpeak()
apiUrl = "https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Bonjour&tl=fr&client=tw-ob"
sndPlaySound32 apiUrl, 0& 
End Sub
```

Can anyone help with that? I also don't want to install the French language pack on my PC to use the windows function.

Thanks

Stephan

Edit:
It seems even the link is not working anymore after google changed the option to download it. So, I just installed the French speech package and use the standard Office function. The only issue is that you cannot change the text language of an excel sheet in Excel as you can do in Word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can play a sound directly from an online URL using sndPlaySound32.
I would try,  save the sound file from the internet to a local directory then play the sound file from local location. Here is an exampel VBA you can try;

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hwnd As Long, _
  ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, _
  ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
  ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub TranslateAndSpeak()
    Dim apiUrl As String
    Dim xhr As Object
    Dim ByteData() As Byte
    Dim strFilePath As String
    
    ' Define the URL
    apiUrl = "https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Bonjour&tl=fr&client=tw-ob"
    
    ' Fetch the file
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xhr.Open "GET", apiUrl, False
    xhr.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    xhr.send
    
    ' Save the file to Temp directory
    strFilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\temp_sound.mp3"
    ByteData = xhr.responseBody
    SaveBinaryData strFilePath, ByteData
    
    ' Play the sound
    PlayWithDefaultPlayer strFilePath
    
End Sub

Sub SaveBinaryData(FilePath As String, ByteData() As Byte)
    Dim lngFileNum As Long
    
    lngFileNum = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Binary Access Write As #lngFileNum
    Put #lngFileNum, , ByteData
    Close #lngFileNum
End Sub

Sub PlayWithDefaultPlayer(FilePath As String)
    ShellExecute 0, "open", FilePath, "", "", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, ChatGpt gave me the exact same solution yesterday. However, it seems to be not working anymore since google changed the API that it cannot be downloaded anymore.